# How to write pattern for get combined words with description from text?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I have sample text:

```
$text = "
АДАБГОЊ љои адаб-
омўзї.
АДАБДОН ادبدان ошно бо адабу фарњанг.
тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тил-
лои холис.
АЁРА اياره 1. ёра, дастбиранљан.
";
```

And I have sample code for get uppercase words to array key and to array value all text right of uppercase words:

```
$regex = '~\b-(?:\R|\h)\b~u';
$text = preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
$pattern = '~^(\p{Lu}+)\h+(.*(?:\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h).*)*)~mu';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
$result = array_combine(array_map('mb_strtolower', $matches[1]), preg_replace('~\s*\R++\s*~u', ' ', preg_replace('~\p{Arabic}+~u', '', $matches[2])));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result exec code:

```
Array
(
    [адабгоњ] => љои адабомўзї. 
    [адабдон] =>  ошно бо адабу фарњанг. тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тиллои холис. 
    [аёра] =>  1. ёра, дастбиранљан. 
)
```

But I have second type text where I have problems:

```
$text = "
АДАБГОЊ//АДАБГАЊ ادبگه//ادبگاه љои адаб-
омўзї.
АДАБДОН ادبدان ошно бо адабу фарњанг.
АЁЃ//АЁЌ т. اياق//اياغ кит. пиёла, ќадањ, соѓар.
АЁР//ИЁР а. ايار санљидани дараљаи холисияти
тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тил-
лои холис.
АЁРА اياره 1. ёра, дастбиранљан.
АДУ//АДУВ а. عدو ниг. адў.
";
```

In this type text I have words with symbols `//`. This type words a two words with one description. (WORD//WORD description). When I use my old code result will be:

```
Array
(
    [адабдон] =>  ошно бо адабу фарњанг. АЁЃ//АЁЌ т. // кит. пиёла, ќадањ, соѓар. АЁР//ИЁР а.  санљидани дараљаи холисияти тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тиллои холис. 
    [аёра] =>  1. ёра, дастбиранљан. АДУ//АДУВ а.  ниг. адў. 
)
```

How to write pattern to get sample result:

```
Array
(
    [адабдон] =>  ошно бо адабу фарњанг. 
    [аёѓ] => т. // кит. пиёла, ќадањ, соѓар. 
    [аёк] => т. // кит. пиёла, ќадањ, соѓар.
    [аёр] => а.  санљидани дараљаи холисияти тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тиллои холис. 
    [иёр] => а.  санљидани дараљаи холисияти тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тиллои холис. 
    [аёра] =>  1. ёра, дастбиранљан.
    [аду] =>  а.  ниг. адў. 
    [адув] =>  а.  ниг. адў. 
)
```

Here to all words with `//` symbol saved one description.

Comment: You never explained what you are trying to do and please use English sample inputs.

Comment: Please publish your working code with a link to https://ideone.com so there will be a starting point for an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way that uses `preg_split`:

```
$text = "
АДАБГОЊ//АДАБГАЊ ادبگه//ادبگاه љои адаб-
омўзї.
АДАБДОН ادبدان ошно бо адабу фарњанг.
АЁЃ//АЁЌ т. اياق//اياغ кит. пиёла, ќадањ, соѓар.
АЁР//ИЁР а. ايار санљидани дараљаи холисияти
тиллову нуќра бо мањак ва ѓ.; зар(р)и иёр тил-
лои холис.
АЁРА اياره 1. ёра, дастбиранљан.
АДУ//АДУВ а. عدو ниг. адў.
";

$defs = preg_split('~^(\p{Lu}+(?://\p{Lu}+)*)\h+~mu', trim($text), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$result = [];
while ( false !== $items = current($defs) ) {
    $def = trim(preg_replace('~(?:\s*\p{Arabic}+(?://\p{Arabic}+)*)?\s+~u', ' ', next($defs)));
    foreach (explode('//', $items) as $item) {
        $result[$item] = $def;
    }
    next($defs);
}

print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/alnEp)

---

Suggestion: if the text comes from a very large file and if you don't need to have the whole array in memory, you can rewrite this code with a user-defined stream filter and eventually a generator that yields keys and values (`yield $key => $value;`) to save memory, example:

```
class NormalizeFilter extends php_user_filter
{
    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            $bucket->data = preg_replace('~\s+\p{Arabic}*(?://\p{Arabic}+)*\s*(?!^\p{Lu})~mu', ' ', $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

stream_filter_register("norm", "NormalizeFilter")
    or die("Failed to register filter");

function genDefs($fh, $bufferSize = 1024) {
    while ( false !== $line = fgets($fh, $bufferSize) ) {
        if ( preg_match('~^(\p{Lu}+(?://\p{Lu}+)*) \K.*\S~u', $line, $m) ) {
            foreach ( explode('//', $m[1]) as $item ) {
                yield $item => $m[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

$fh = fopen('php://filter/read=norm/resource=file:///path/to/file.txt', 'r');

$defs = genDefs($fh);

foreach ($defs as $item => $definition) {
    echo "$item: $definition\n";
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/13eIX)
[variant](https://3v4l.org/Lgv9i)

Comment: older I not use generators in php. Can you show me example code with yield generator? I have file with size 13mb. I must test code with it. If it possible show me example using yield with this task.

Comment: @Otabek: I added an example.